# DataGridView.Row changes

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have some issues using DataGridView. What I'm trying to do is editing some data in a DataGridView, verify that data and if it is correct to safe it this way and if not to restore it to the previous state. What I'm doing is:

- Use Cell.Enter event so I can safe dataGridView.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem into Object 1 before editing current cell.
- Use Cell.Leave event where I check if data in this cell is as expected. Here I have some troubles. If I go like that even handler is activated on the second Cell.Leave and if I add DataGridView.EndEdit() Object 1 updates with the current value.

Everything works fine if validation is true.

Tried to clone my object (not sure if I have done it right tho) didn't work as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to do all of the stuff you are doing. DataGridView has got built-in support for validation, acceptance of valid data and rejection of invalid entries.

Simply use `CellValidating` event of your DataGridView and perform your validation logic in there. If the input data does not pass your tests, you can set `e.Cancel` to `True` and the cell will revert to original value.